# set left X-position of UITableViewCellAccessory

Tags: uitableview

in moreNavigationController I try to change the arrow position in cells.
It works on an iPhone but not on an iPad.

The origin X-position on the iPhone is AFTER the seperator line ends,
on the iPad it's much more BEFORE the separator ends.

It works fine to change the position more to the left side with this Code on an iPhone:

```
        UIImageView *arrowImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed : AppInfo::getArrowIconResource()]];
        [[-moreTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:row] setAccessoryView : arrowImage];

        CGRect frame     = arrowImage.frame;
        frame.size.width = 50;
        arrowImage.frame = frame;
        [arrowImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeLeft];
```

The arrow position in the cell changed to the left! And it ends with the separator line.

On the iPad nothing seems to change the x-Position to the right (so the separator line is too long).
It does not matter which value i set (50,-50), nothing change the arrow more to the right position.

```
  [arrowImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeRight]; has no effect
```

Has any an idea?